# Effective way to create a full width header, while keeping the content under a restricted width

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, cloudpage

Currently I'm faced with a design issue I cannot figure out how to remedy.

I'm new to Salesforce Marketing Cloud, prior I developed web applications in an isolated and less restricting development environment which deploys to a CMS.

We recently switched to Salesforce Marketing Cloud to handle our operations. I'm finding it hard to keep brand styles and providing a seamless transition into this new platform.

My current situation presents the problem of creating a header that's full width while keeping the content below it restricted to 1160px. We want to try and keep the content editable with the drag and drop functionality of the content builder.

How can I simulate the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <img src="src.jpg" style="width:100%; padding:0" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
               <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <img src="src.jpg" style="width:100%; padding:0" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```